# How can I code an ordered logistic regression for panel data in R?

Tags: r, panel-data, ordered-logit

I am writing my thesis, and I am trying to test the relationship between transnational counterterrorism and state repression in countries of intervention. My independent variable is counterterrorism aid (continuous) and my dependent variable is human rights violations (ordinal). I have unbalanced panel data, where there is information on the CT. aid that a country received in a certain year and the human rights violations perpetrated by the state. I want to found out whether counterterrorism aid increases state repression in the countries that receive this assistance.
How can I conduct a ordered logistic regression in R for panel data? Is that even possible? If not I would appreciate very much suggestions for other models.